# Android - ToggleButton setChecked and setSelected not working

Tags: android, state, sharedpreferences, togglebutton

What I am trying to do is checking the `SharedPreferences` if the volume and vibration is `on` or `off`. 
If it is on the `ToggleButton` should be set to `on`, else, `off`.

I already tried using `setChecked()` and `setSelected()` on `ToggleButton`s but it didn't change the `TogggleButton`s' state.

I also tried initializing a variable for the `true` and `false` just to make sure but still doesn't work.

**What seems to be the problem?**

```
    optionsDB = getSharedPreferences(table, 0);

    String volReturned = optionsDB.getString("volume", "Couldn't load data");
    String vibReturned = optionsDB.getString("vibration", "Couldn't load data");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Vol: "+volReturned+" Vib: "+ vibReturned, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    boolean boolT = true;
    boolean boolF = false;
    if (volReturned=="On"){
        /*tbtnvol.setChecked(true);*/
        tbtnvol.setSelected(boolT);
    }else{
        tbtnvol.setSelected(boolF);
        }
    if (vibReturned=="On"){
        tbtnvib.setSelected(boolT);
    }else{
        tbtnvib.setSelected(boolF);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `==` use `.equals()` for string comparison..

Try this,

```
if (volReturned.equals("On")){
        /*tbtnvol.setChecked(true);*/
        tbtnvol.setSelected(boolT);
    }else{
        tbtnvol.setSelected(boolF);
        }
    if (vibReturned.equals("On")){
        tbtnvib.setSelected(boolT);
    }else{
        tbtnvib.setSelected(boolF);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are two methods associated with ToggleView:

1. setChecked(Boolean value)
2. setSelected(Boolean value)

And both of them are to be used in pair. If you want to set toggle view selected, pass "true" to **both** these methods and vice-versa.

The reason being, setChecked() *sets the intrinsic boolean dataMember* associated with your view object and setSelected *sets the UI associated* with your view object.

Yes, this is wired and actually one method should set both UI and data, but this is how it was implemented and thus this is how we must use these methods-in pair.